# Vapor Installation Issues (First time using Vapor) using Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, vapor

After installing vapor i am getting below error

`dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/vapor
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6`

Here lies my issue, I have no idea how to solve that.even I am not able to create new project.
Please help.

Comment: Which operating system(s) and version(s) are you targeting? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I never faced with that issue but saw this tricky solution in some chat

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
```

or maybe `libressl` needed

```sh
brew install libressl
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ?

```
brew update && brew upgrade
brew install openssl
```